# Asking to terminate my google colab notebook repeatedly

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

This happened like 100th time today. I tried to decrease the size of the data even though it didn't stop. If you notice there is only 1 notebook that's running and it occupied just 1gb ram.
Can someone help me fix this

[image]

Comment: Does this issue reproduce in an incognito window with extensions disabled? (The most common cause of this type of behavior is a misbehaving extension.)

Comment: I've tried this on incognito too and the problem is still there. But today I didn't find this issue. It resolved automatically I guess